# typeorm - relational searches with limit

Tags: sql, typeorm

First of all, I apologize for my English, but come on. My problem is in the code snippet below. My application is an API built in Nodejs, using TypeScript, and I use TypeORM as ORM. I'm querying the database for a category and its services, but TypeORM doesn't offer "take" or "skip" options for relational queries. How can I resolve this?

```
  async findOneByIdWithServicesAndServicesImages(
    id: string,
    skip: number,
    limit: number
  ): Promise<Category | undefined> {
    const category = await this.repository.findOne({
      where: { id },
      select: {
        ...categorySelect,
        services: { ...serviceSelect, images: serviceImageSelect },
      },
      relations: { services: { images: true } },
      //take
      //skip
    });
    return category !== null ? category : undefined;
  }
```

One approach I thought of would be to completely separate the responsibilities of the repositories, where each repository would only look after its entity. Then at the service or controller layer I would call the methods needed to construct a response. Could this approach be resource intensive by opening a new query on every call? I know this can be inefficient in terms of scalability, but do you think this approach is valid?